# Showing a curve which lays on a sphere of radius 1 is plane

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

Assuming $\alpha$ is a unit speed curve, I'm trying to prove that $\alpha$ is plane. By hypothesis, I know its curvature is such that
$$\kappa=1$$
I'm trying to use the torsion's formula:
$$\tau=\frac{\langle \alpha'\times\alpha'',\alpha'''\rangle}{\|\alpha'\times\alpha''\|^{2}}$$
to show it's equal to zero, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Don't you need to define the space curve?

Comment: @Narasimham Actually, no. I mean, the exercise just asks to prove it, just like I wrote.

Comment: Are you asking if a unit speed curve on a sphere of radius $1$ with $\kappa = 1$ is a *plane curve*?

Comment: @RobertLewis the exercise I'm doing is asking to prove this: "If $\alpha$ is a curve that lays on a sphere of radius 1, show $\kappa\geq1$. Still, show if $\kappa=1$, then $\alpha$ is plane. The first part I made it, the problem is the last one.

Comment: @mvfs314: thanks.  Will see if I can come up with anything.  ***Cheers!***

Comment: The problem is miswritten, as Robert pointed out. $\alpha$ will be a *planar* curve, i.e., a circle on the sphere. In fact, it will be a great circle (why?). Do *not* use the torsion formula. Do you know about normal curvature? What is normal curvature on the unit sphere? And what happens when curvature equals normal curvature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a unit speed curve that lies on the sphere of radius 1 we have $\langle \alpha, \alpha\rangle = 1 = \langle \alpha^\prime, \alpha^\prime\rangle$. From this, it follows $2\langle \alpha', \alpha\rangle =0$.
Then differentiating once more, we get $0=\langle \alpha'',\alpha\rangle + \langle \alpha',\alpha'\rangle = \langle \alpha'',\alpha\rangle + 1$ which implies $\alpha'' = -\alpha$, since $1=k=\lVert \alpha''\rVert$, and $\lVert\alpha\rVert = 1$.
Finally we have $\alpha '''= -\alpha'\implies \alpha'''\parallel\alpha '\implies \langle \alpha'\times \alpha'', \alpha'''\rangle =0\implies \tau = 0$